# Getting a "Insufficient Permission [403]" error when trying to access Google Search Console API

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

I'm performing authorization like this:

```
        ClientSecrets secrets;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(keyFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
        }

        var scopes = new[]
        {
            AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly,
            WebmastersService.Scope.WebmastersReadonly,
        };

        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            scopes,
            AppSettings.Instance.UserName,
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new WebmastersService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "MyApp",
        });

        var sites = service.Sites.List().Execute();
```

After this, I can create an instance of WebmastersService successfully; however, all operations fail with the "Insufficient Permission" error. The Google Search Console API  is already enabled in the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/enabled website. I can successfully access the Google Analytics API using the same credentials.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Time has passed, but it might still be usefull for someone... :)

I'm using X509Certificate class to load my keyfile and it works like a charm.

```
ConnectionEmail = "aaaaaa@aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
ConnectionPassword = "notasecret";
ConnectionKey = File.ReadAllBytes("keyfile.p12");

Scopes = new[]
{
    WebmastersService.Scope.Webmasters
};

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(ConnectionKeyBytes, ConnectionPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

Service = new WebmastersService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ConnectionEmail) { Scopes = Scopes, }.FromCertificate(certificate)
    )
});
```